# Is it possible to connect to login screen on console session via VNC or RDP?

Tags: login, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp, vino

Following the instructions from [Use xrdp to connect to desktop session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235905/use-xrdp-to-connect-to-desktop-session), I've set up xrdp/vino so that if I'm logged on at the console, I can remote in and share the desktop.

However, my question is if it's possible to set up VNC server to share the console's login screen, allowing me to log in at the console remotely.

I'm not talking about the VNC/RDP login screen, which is different than the console's login screen.

The console session is usually logged in, but in the event I have to reboot remotely, I would like to log back into the console session so when I return home, the session will be accessible on the physical machine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wait, you are saying to reboot the host/remote system and you get your session back?

Comment: Someting like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/103321/installing-vnc-with-resumable-sessions?

Comment: @Braiam No, I'm saying if I reboot my host remotely, I want to access the session remotely that my physical display sees/shares.

Comment: @Takkat Will try running x11vnc as root.